# Android Login Activity Template

Tags: java, android, eclipse, authentication, android-activity

What and where should I add code to make it work?
By default It does not do anything, the button shows "sign in or register" but it doesn't shows any registration activity.
"Recover lost password" in the menu also does nothing.
I managed to open a new activity after signing by creating an intent after finish();
though it logins successfully irrespective of the email and password!

## EDIT: Here's the code!

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity 
{
/**
 * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
 * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
 */
private static final String[] CREDENTIALS = new String[] 
        {
        "myaccount1@gmail.com:12345", "myaccount2@gmail.com:54321" 
        };

/**
 * The default email to populate the email field with.
 */
public static final String EXTRA_EMAIL = "myaccount1@gmail.com";

/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */
private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

// Values for email and password at the time of the login attempt.
private String mEmail;
private String mPassword;

// UI references.
private EditText mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mLoginFormView;
private View mLoginStatusView;
private TextView mLoginStatusMessageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Set up the login form.
    mEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL);
    mEmailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mEmailView.setText(mEmail);

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id,
                        KeyEvent keyEvent) 
                {
                    if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) 
                    {
                        attemptLogin();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mLoginStatusView = findViewById(R.id.login_status);
    mLoginStatusMessageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_status_message);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) 
                {
                    attemptLogin();
                }
            });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
 * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
 * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
 */
public void attemptLogin() 
{
    if (mAuthTask != null) 
    {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    mEmail = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    mPassword = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPassword)) 
    {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (mPassword.length() < 4) 
    {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEmail)) 
    {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!mEmail.contains("@")) 
    {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) 
    {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else 
    {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        mLoginStatusMessageView.setText(R.string.login_progress_signing_in);
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) 
{
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) 
    {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) 
                    {
                        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) 
                    {
                        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE
                                : View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
    } else 
    {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> 
{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try 
        {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (String credential : CREDENTIALS) 
        {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) 
            {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        //CREDENTIALS[2]=mEmail+":"+mPassword;  tried this for regisration
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) 
    {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) 
        {
            finish();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,CalculatorActivity.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        } else 
        {
            mPasswordView
                    .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() 
    {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

}

This works well for the default strings in the CREDENTIALS but I don't know how to implement the registration process, how do I add those mEmail and mPassword to the CREDENTIALS string?

Comment: Ok so are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Post some code and we can help.

Comment: The template you are talking about is just a mere template, just the very basic basic layout, it is intended to be a starting step for the developer, not the entire process.. Especially that the process varies based on the requirements.

Comment: Can you please find me a tutorial? I didn't found any and Yes @Mark eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

CREDENTIALS is just a string array defined in the first few lines of the program and you can edit it manually. for exmaple:

```
private static final String[] CREDENTIALS = new String[] 
        {
        "myaccount1@gmail.com:12345", "myaccount2@gmail.com:54321", "bla@bla.com:1234" 
        };
```

But this template code is intended for login against a webservice database or something similar. If you want to login against a local database you don't need the AsyncTask mumbo jumbo, you could just write the authentication code in the attemptlogin() function, when cancel != true.